# how to I remove/disable an android button[Beginner]

Tags: android, button, processing

Let me start off by saying that this is my first time posting on Stackoverflow as most of my questions have been already answered by this great community.

I am trying to make a very simple program in which buttons are selected and a string is saved according to the button.

I am able to select the button on GUI1 and then display my GUI2 but the buttons I created in GUI1 are still in the background and still enabled.

I would like to remove them or disable them altogether so that i do not have buttons overlapping.

```
Button want;
Button dwant;

Button eat;
Button sleep;
Button play;
Button read;
Button swim;


boolean showGUI1 = true;
boolean showGUI2 = false;

color bgCol = color(255);

void setup()
{
 size(550, 900);

 want = new Button("Want",140,300,250,150); 
 dwant = new Button("Dont Want",140,590,250,150);

 eat = new Button("Eat",140,300,200,100); 
 sleep = new Button("Sleep",140,400,200,100); 
 play = new Button("Play",140,500,200,100); 
 read = new Button("Read",140,600,200,100); 
 swim = new Button("Swim",140,700,200,100); 

}

void draw()
{
  background(bgCol);

  if (showGUI1)
{
     want.display();
     dwant.display();
  }

  if (showGUI2)
  {
 eat.display();
 sleep.display();
 play.display();
 read.display();
 swim.display();

  }

}

    void mouseReleased()
    {
      if(want.mouseReleased())  
  {
    bgCol = color(255,0,0);
    choice= "Want";
    showGUI1 = false;
    showGUI2 = true;

  }

  if(dwant.mouseReleased())
  {
    bgCol = color(0,255,0);
    choice= "Dont Want";
    showGUI1 = false;
    showGUI2 = true;

   }

//action  GUI2 showing
    if(eat.mouseReleased())  
  {
    action= "Eat";

    showGUI2 = false;

  }

  if(sleep.mouseReleased())
  {
    action= "Sleep";

    showGUI2 = false;

  }

  if(play.mouseReleased())  
  {
    action= "Play";

    showGUI2 = false;

  }

  if(read.mouseReleased())
  {
    action= "Read";

    showGUI2 = false;

  }

  if(swim.mouseReleased())
  {
    action= "Swim";

    showGUI2 = false;

}
```

for my Button I am using the following code

```
Button(String nm, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
super(nm, x, y, w, h);
}

void display()
{
  if(currentImage != null)
  {
    float imgWidth = (extents.y*currentImage.width)/currentImage.height;

  pushStyle();
  imageMode(CORNER);
  tint(imageTint);
  image(currentImage, pos.x, pos.y, imgWidth, extents.y);
  stroke(bgColor);
  noFill();
  rect(pos.x, pos.y, imgWidth,  extents.y);
  noTint();
  popStyle();
}
else
{
  pushStyle();
  stroke(lineColor);
  fill(bgColor);
  rect(pos.x, pos.y, extents.x, extents.y);

  fill(lineColor);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(name, pos.x + 0.5*extents.x, pos.y + 0.5* extents.y);
  popStyle();
}
```

}

I can also use the ControlP5 library for buttons but even in that I dont know how to activate the "controlP5.Controller : Button hide() " (hide function)

If anyone could shed some light it would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, for removing them you can use button.setVisibility(View.GONE), which will remove them and they won't take any layout space. However if you want to hide them but keep the space they occupy, use button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE).

If on the other side you want to still see them, but just disable them, use button.setEnabled(false).

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried adding "import android.view.View;" in order to use the "button.setVisibility(View.GONE)" function but it gives me the error that "the package "android" does not exist, you might be missing a library" how should I approach this?